# Combining JOIN with getting "child" rows

Tags: mysql, sql

To make a question simplier let's suppose we are having two tables with few columns and one-to-many relation...

1. `first` with fields `id`, `some_field` and `second_id`.
2. `second` with fields `id`, `parent_id`

First I do

```
SELECT first.id, first.some_field, second.id, second.parent_id 
FROM first INNER JOIN second ON first.second_id = second.id 
WHERE some_field="some_val"
```

But after that I need to get `first.id`, `first.some_field`, `second.id` from join of two tables where `parent_id` is among values in respective column of result of the above query.

Is that can be done with one query? Or (on PHP side) I need to take column in result set and do something like the following?

```
SELECT first.id, first.some_field, second.id, second.parent_id 
FROM first INNER JOIN second ON first.second_id = second.id 
WHERE parent_id IN (<many_ids_here>)
```

Comment: This is done as a hierarchical query or a recursive query.  Unfortunately mySQL doesn't support these concepts.  There is a work around using global variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query  or you have to repeat joins between tables for the # of levels you wish to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a nested query, like this:

```
SELECT first.id, first.some_field, second.id, second.parent_id 
FROM first INNER JOIN second ON first.second_id = second.id 
WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT second.parent_id FROM first INNER JOIN second ON first.second_id = second.id WHERE some_field="some_val")
```

Comment: that's not bad advice and what if I need data from first query united with data from this one? Is there something better then doing `UNION`

Comment: Got it now! All I need is just one `OR`